# ddrescue .NTFS file can't open file

Tags: partition, data-recovery, ntfs, ddrescue

I have just rescued an old damaged HDD to my 8TB drive and I've got 1 `.IMG` file.

I then took the 8TB drive to my work Windows 10 machine and used 7-zip to extract the file.

Then I got 2 `.NTFS` files that I can't open or extract. I have used `ddrescue` with no problems before.

What do I need so I can open the `.NTFS` file?

I have tried Test disk and copied the .ntfs file but I just get this file .ntfs that I can't open; I know all data is in this .ntfs file!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Nothing happens new picture]

[image: New error]
This new error

[image: New Command]
New Command

Answer (score 3):

`ddrescue` takes the raw contents of a partition, disk, or even a file and writes them to either a partition, disk, or file; doing its best to grab all the content.

When you rescue a partition to a file you end up with an "image" file containing the raw contents of the partition. To access the files in the partition/filesystem you can either restore the image to a partition of equal or larger size: `dd if=ntfs.img of=/dev/sdb1`

Or you can mount the image: `mount -o loop ntfs.img /some/directory`

**Note:** I'm making the assumption you're familiar with `dd` and `mount`. If not, please read their man pages before using those comments. Especially so for `dd`.

Comment: Thanks for answering me :)

Im new to Ubunto and DDrescue but i used ddrescue maybe 4 times and got all data out but im stuck here :/ 

i use this command here: 
sudo ddrescue -D  /dev/sdd '/media/torp/TEST/985PeterChristiansen/drive.img' '/media/torp/985PeterChristiansen/drive.log'

and this is the sourche of the img file /media/torp/TEST/985PeterChristiansen/drive.img

Can you help me with the code in terminal i need to use to get the data out ?? :)

Comment: Try: `sudo mkdir /mnt/peter && sudo mount -o loop '/media/torp/TEST/985PeterChristiansen/drive.img /mnt/peter` You should then see the files in `/mnt/peter`

Comment: See the picture in my first question or the code is here i just renamed the folders and the drive see picture

sudo mkdir /mnt/peter1 && sudo mount -o loop '/media/torp/TEST Torp IT/985/drive.img /mnt/peter1

is this right ?? :) and thanks again for helping med :)

Comment: @Stalkmis, the example commands I provided execute two `sudo` in sequence. The first command creates a directory to act as a mount point for your NTFS filesystem; Hence if you have a directory for this purpose already you can skip `mkdir`. The second command mounts the image created by ddrescue` at the mount point. Feel free to adjust the command arguments as needed, referencing the man pages to clarify how the commands work. I can tell you exactly what to run, but you'd learn more by digging into it yourself. Given both commands are safe to execute, it's unlikely you'll mess something up.

Comment: i see now but when i use this command sudo mkdir /mnt/peter  it says file exist


then i go to the command: sudo mount -o loop '/media/torp/TEST/985PeterChristiansen/drive.img nothing happens (see 
 new picture in my first question?? :) 

And last where is it mounted ??

Thanks for helping med :) i know i have to learn its just this person im recovering for is not so patient :P

Comment: Ah, I made a typo: There shouldn't be a single-quote before /media.

Comment: I think i got it now but i says a error see the new picture :/ :D

Comment: Perhaps your image is of a disk rather than a partition. You can check by running `fdisk -l /path/to/ntfs/image`

Comment: Its of a damage HDD the entire disk is cloned :) See new picture i made the command what now ?? :) *Thanks 

its these 2 i need data from /media/torp/TEST Torp IT/drive.img2            821248 313391103 312569856      149G  7 HPFS
/media/torp/TEST Torp IT/drive.img3         313391104 625141759 311750656    148,7G  7 HPFS

Comment: Use `sudo losetup --show -f -P /path/to/ntfs/image` to create block devices for each partition in your image. You'll see devices such as `/dev/loop0p1`, where loop represents the whole "disk" and p1 a partition of that "disk" image. Then you can use `mount` to mount the partitions you need. Finally, use something like `losetup -d /dev/loop0p1` to detach all of the block devices. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39675265/5171219